# Cómo ajustar imagen dentro de un td en una tabla?

Tags: javascript, html, css, table

Tengo un problema con una imagen dentro de una tabla, me ocupa más contenido del que necesito que ocupe, estoy haciendo un carrito con js vanilla y construí una tabla para el carrito y quiero mandar dentro la imagen del producto en cuestión, el tema es que ocupa más de lo que necesito, más que nada el background, pq la imagen si la achiqué, pero si le doy un color de fondo, todavía se pinta, necesito que se ajuste al tamaño de la imagen, si alguien tiene una idea o podría brindarme un poco de orientación estaría agradecido.

[image: Así es cmo me queda]

```js
//Este es el código en Js

const llenarCarrito = () => {

  // Limpiar antes de ciclo
  items.innerHTML = "";

  const template = d.getElementById("template-carrito").content;
  const fragment = d.createDocumentFragment();

  Object.values(carrito).forEach(producto => {

    console.log(producto);

    template.querySelectorAll("td")[0].querySelector("img").setAttribute("src", producto.imageUrl);
    template.querySelectorAll("td")[1].textContent = producto.title;
    template.querySelectorAll("td")[2].textContent = producto.cantidad;
    template.querySelector("span").textContent = producto.precio * producto.cantidad;

    // Botones
    //    template.querySelector("btn-info").dataset.id = producto.id;
    // template.querySelector("btn-danger").dataset.id = producto.id;

    const clone = template.cloneNode(true);
    fragment.appendChild(clone);
  })

  items.appendChild(fragment);

}
```

```html
<!-- Este es el template en HTML -->

<template id="template-carrito">
      <tr>
        <td class="bg-danger"><img class="w-25" src="" alt=""></td>
        <td>Café</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm">
                +
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                -
            </button>
        </td>
        <td>$ <span>500</span></td>
      </tr>
    </template>
```

Comment: Yo acostumbro a poner un `width="1"` como atributo a la columna y como la imagen es más grande igualmente lo hace más grande, aunque no se si es muy ortodoxo, la verdad:  `<td width="1" class="bg-danger">`.  Eso si, si las imágenes tienen tamaños distintos siempre cogerá el ancho más grande dejando las otras con porciones del fondo a la vista.

Comment: Gracias, me funcionó modificando el width del </td>